# overlay with flexbox and overflow

Tags: html, css

On a checkout page I make an overlay on top of the website where scroll on body is disabled, but overflow is enabled on the overlay.

But if the viewport is smaller the content on the overlay is clipped.

How to avoid that?

I tried to add `overflow:auto` to the overlay but it didn't work :

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#overlay.active {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay" class="active">
  <div style="height:300px; background:white; padding:20px">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It seems that adding `margin: auto` on the child `div` where content is can solve this:

```
#overlay > div { margin: auto; }
```

Use `safe` for `align-items` would be a good solution but it only work on Firefox as of now:

```
align-items: safe center;
```

Example:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/*  Added on the child div */
#overlay > div {
  margin: auto;
}

#overlay.active {
  position: fixed;
  /*  Can use shorthand (Optional: not supported by older browsers and IE) */
  inset: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*  Safe is only working on Firefox as of now  */
  align-items: safe center;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay" class="active">
  <div style="height:300px; background:white; padding:20px">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its still not working :(

Comment: your own example clip the top of the content

Comment: @clarkk My bad, I did not test it on another browser other than Firefox, just realized the `safe` solution only works there. I update another method that can be tried and hopefully it would help.

Comment: thanks.. but its still too risky to use `inset` property. It's fairly new and not supported by older browsers

Comment: @clarkk Very true, I revised the comment so it highlights the potential compatibility concern. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `align-items:center;` that you have on #overlay.active, the content then scrolls as expected. The #overlay.active only has a single child item, so align-items (which would define how flex items are laid out along the cross axis on the current line) does not actually have any visual effect